# Split Column in txt file in Python

Tags: python-2.7, multiple-columns

I am a beginner in python. I have made a small script with python 2.7.11 to get data from an Agilent equipment but the format is not ideal.
So far, I have managed to format my data as follow in a txt file:

freq1

freq2

...

freq201

data1

data2

...

data201

and I would like to format them as follow, so that I can easisly open the txt file with excel:

freq1    ; data1

freq2    ; data2

...      ; ...

freq201  ; data201

Do you know of any easy way to achieve that ?

Thanks in advance

CL

Comment: Is there a one to one mapping and it's guaranteed that there's N lines of freq and then N lines of data? If so and you can load the file into memory - you can then split it into two parts and zip them together

Comment: Yes, there will be 201 lines of frequency and 201 lines of data for 95% of my measurements. how can I load the file into memory, split it and zip it back ? Will I be able to use a ";" character to zip back the columns together ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the same number of lines of freq and lines of data, this bit of code should do the trick:

```
#imports OrderedDict to have an Ordered dictionary
from collections import OrderedDict

#opens files
my_file = open('freq.txt','r')
my_new_file = open("new.txt",'w')

#saves lines of file as a list, with each line being one item in the list
lines_list = my_file.readlines()

#creates empty dictionary to fill with data
freq_data = OrderedDict()

#iterates through lines and adds to dictionary, with freq as key and data as value
for line in range(len(lines_list)/2):
    freq_data[lines_list[line]] = lines_list[line+10]
    keys = freq_data.keys()

#writes to your new file
for i in keys:
    my_new_file.write(i.strip() + ' ; ' + freq_data[i])

#closes both files
my_file.close()
my_new_file.close()
```

Essentially what this code does is opens your file, connects each freq to a corresponding data value, and then writes that into a new file. You can change the line

```
freq_data[lines_list[line]] = lines_list[line+10]
```

to whatever number of lines your data has divided by two, so for you it would be

```
freq_data[lines_list[line]] = lines_list[line+201]
```

This turns the text file that looks like:

> freq1 freq2 freq3 ... data1 data2 data3

...
into

> freq1 ; data1
>
> freq2 ; data2
>
> freq3 ; data3 ...

Hope this helps!